# Ansible ping fails when I am not using root priviledges

Tags: docker, ssh, ansible

I get the following error when I try to ping another docker container I setup as a remote:

```
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: bind: File name too long\r\nunix_listener: cannot bind to path: /var/jenkins_home/.ansible/cp/jenkins_remote-22-remote_user.15sibyvAohxbTCvh",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

However, when I run the same command using the root user, it works.

I have tried to add add the following command to my ansible.cfg file, but it still fails.

```
control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%p-%%r
```

Please what could be the issue?

Comment: is the ansible user which you are using, is part of docker group? if not I think that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue it worked with root user and printed the same error otherwise. What did help was to add the following:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
control_path = /dev/shm/cp%%h-%%p-%%r
```

to `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file (create it if it doesn't exist).